# Datatables colVis use column name instead of index

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables-1.10

I'm using datatables 1.10 with the colVis extension. I would like to be able to hide columns based on their name, not their index.

So instead of this:

```
"colVis": {"exclude": [17],  "buttonText": "Columns"}
```

I'd like to use the new datatables API and do something like this:

```
"colVis": {"exclude": [oTable.column( 'priority:name' ).index()],  "buttonText": "Columns"}
```

Priority being the name of the column I wish to hide.

Anyone have any idea how to do it this way?

Comment: You cannot, since you cannot use the API object before it is initialized. `oTable.column( 'priority:name' ).index()` or `this.column( 'priority:name' ).index()` inside the dataTables constructor is an attempt to use the API before it is initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by just adding the colVis after you initialize the table. Doing something like this...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.ColVis(table, {
        exclude: [table.column('priority:name').index()],
        buttonText: "Columns"
    });

    $(colvis.button()).insertAfter('.someDiv');
});
</script>
```